# Не запускается Spring Cloud сервис конфигурации

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Я изучаю микросервисную архитектуру по книге "Микросервисы Spring в действии". В книге есть пример сервиса конфирурации spring cloud, которую я хочу повторить. Вот так выглядит проектный pom файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.aoizora</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <docker.image.prefix>ostock</docker.image.prefix>
        <slf4j.version>2.0.11</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>push</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Главный класс приложения такой:

```
package aoizora;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

И дальше пошли конфиги. Файл main/resources/bootstrap.yml, который обрабатывается первым при запуске приложения:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:/config

server:
  port: 8071
```

Здесь говорится, что конфиги ищутся в classpath в папке main/resources/config. В этой папке находятся еще два конфига: основной и для dev окружения. Но приложение не может запуститься. При запуске главного класса я получаю такую ошибку:

> 2024-01-16T22:40:00.377+02:00  INFO 42521 --- [           main]
> o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
> embedded WebApplicationContext 2024-01-16T22:40:00.378+02:00  INFO
> 42521 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext :
> Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 789 ms
> 2024-01-16T22:40:00.789+02:00  WARN 42521 --- [           main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in
> class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'healthContributorRegistry' parameter 2: Error creating bean with name
> 'configServerHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration$ConfigServerActuatorConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0: Error creating bean with
> name 'searchPathCompositeEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/CompositeConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'searchPathCompositeEnvironmentRepository' parameter 0: Error creating
> bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]:
> You need to configure a uri for the git repository.
> 2024-01-16T22:40:00.792+02:00  INFO 42521 --- [           main]
> o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
> 2024-01-16T22:40:00.806+02:00  INFO 42521 --- [           main]
> .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation
> report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> 2024-01-16T22:40:00.815+02:00 ERROR 42521 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Invalid config server configuration.
>
> Action:
>
> If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your
> configuration.  If you have set
> spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite
> configuration.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Что я сделал не так и почему возникла эта ошибка? Как ее исправить?